# Regular Expression to match set of arbitrary codes

Tags: regex

I am looking for some help on creating a regular expression that would work with a unique input in our system.  We already have some logic in our keypress event that will only allow digits, and will allow the letter A and the letter M.  Now I need to come up with a RegEx that can match the input during the `onblur` event to ensure the format is correct.

I have some examples below of what would be valid.  The letter A represents an age, so it is always followed by up to 3 digits.  The letter M can only occur at the end of the string.

### Valid Input

1-M
10-M
100-M
5-7
5-20
5-100
10-20
10-100
A5-7
A10-7
A100-7
A10-20
A5-A7
A10-A20
A10-A100
A100-A102

### Invalid Input

a-a
a45
4

Comment: poorly worded question, please make it clearer in the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches all of the samples.

```
/A?\d{1,3}-A?\d{0,3}M?/
```

Not sure if 10-A10M should or shouldn't be legal or even if M can appear with numbers. If it M is only there without numbers:

```
/A?\d{1,3}-(A?\d{1,3}|M)/
```

Comment: In your second version, the digits only alternative is superfluous (also covered by the optional-A-plus-digits alternative).

Comment: No it won't. There must be a digit or an M at a minimum on the right.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[A]?[0-9]{1,3}-[A]?[0-9]{1,3}[M]?$/
```

Matches anything of the form:

```
A(optional)[1-3 numbers]-A(optional)[1-3 numbers]M(optional)
```

Comment: You don't need the character class square brackets around the A or M letters.

Comment: @Jonathan - I know, but I tend to do that out of habit. It's one of my many "coding practices"

@Gumbo - I don't see why not... enlighten me?

Comment: Because your second range says exactly '{3}' instead of '{1,3}'.

Answer (score 2):

Use the brute force method if you have a small amount of well defined patterns so you don't get bad corner-case matches:

```
^(\d+-M|\d+-\d+|A\d+-\d+|A\d+-A\d+)$
```

Here are the individual regexes broken out:

```
\d+-M      <- matches anything like '1-M'
\d+-\d+    <- 5-7
A\d+-\d+   <- A5-7
A\d+-A\d+  <- A10-A20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^A?\d+-(?:A?\d+|M)$
```

An optional A followed by one or more digits, a dash, and either another optional A and some digits or an M.  The '`(?: ... )`' notation is a Perl 'non-capturing' set of parentheses around the alternatives; it means there will be no '`$1`' after the regex matches.  Clearly, if you wanted to capture the various bits and pieces, you could - and would - do so, and the non-capturing clause might not be relevant any more.

(You could replace the '`+`' with '`{1,3}`' as JasonV did to limit the numbers to 3 digits.)

Comment: You forgot the '?' quantifier after the second A.

Answer (score 1):

```
^A?\d{1,3}-(M|A?\d{1,3})$
```

^ -- the match must be done from the beginning
A? -- "A" is optional
\d{1,3} -- between one and 3 digits; [0-9]{1,3} also work
- -- A "-" character
(...|...) -- Either one of the two expressions
(M|...) -- Either "M" or...
(...|A?\d{1,3}) -- "A" followed by at least one and at most three digits
$ -- the match should be done to the end

Some consequences of changing the format. If you do not put "^" at the beginning, the match may ignore an invalid beginning. For example, "MAAMA0-M" would be matched at "A0-M".

If, likewise, you leave $ out, the match may ignore an invalid trail. For example, "A0-MMMMAAMAM" would match "A0-M".

Using \d is usually preferred, as is \w for alphanumerics, \s for spaces, \D for non-digit, \W for non-alphanumeric or \S for non-space. But you must be careful that \d is not being treated as an escape sequence. You might need to write it \\d instead.

{x,y} means the last match must occur between x and y times.

? means the last match must occur once or not at all.

When using (), it is treated as one match. (ABC)? will match ABC or nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I’d use this regular expression:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}-(?:M|[1-9]\d{0,2})|A[1-9]\d{0,2}-A?[1-9]\d{0,2})$
```

This matches either:

- *`<number>`*`-M` or *`<number>`*`-`*`<number>`*
- **`A`**`<number>`**`-`**`<number>` or **`A`**`<number>`**`-A`**`<number>`

Additionally *`<number>`* must not begin with a `0`.